# What is the flow of execution of this code?

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (!print "hi")
    if (print "hello")
print "hi";
?>
```

I think print, prints hi and then it return 1 which evaluates to 0 so nested if is not reached, and then it prints hi one more time.
So a/c to me the output should be : 
hihi
But the answer is hi, Why is that ?

Comment: `print` always returns `1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the bad indentation, the third `print` statement is the conditional result of the second `if` statement.

i.e. it means the same as:

```
<?php
if (!print "hi") {
    if (print "hello") {
        print "hi";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Good reason to always use braces in PHP.

Comment: Reason #32 why I don't understand criticism of languages using significant whitespace… :-3

Comment: Okay so second hi is never reached, I thought it was not a part of any of the if statements. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if we have if(print "hi" - 1)

Comment: @RahulRanjan `if` **must** have something happening on true, or at least have `{}`, otherwise you would get an error. You can test yourself what would be the result then, but I believe it would be the same. Or you would get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Because php is not python)
It does not care about the tabulation, if brackets are omitted only first line will belong to the "if" construction.
So your code is:

```
if (!print "hi") {
    if (print "hello") {
        print "hi";
    }
}
```